# Save data to variable and use it in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax

I have a table of 2 columns `(Date, Text)`. I am getting data from the `Text` column according to the `Date` using a query like this:

```
SELECT Text
FROM MyTable
WHERE Date>= @userDate;
```

This works, except when `@userDate` is bigger than the most recent `Date` in `MyTable`. In this case it returns nothing but I need it to return the `Text` for the most recent Date.

I have to change my query to use the smaller one of `@userDate` and `MAX(Date)`. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tablename varchar(100)='site'
DECLARE @table1 table(date1 date)
INSERT INTO @table1
EXEC ('SELECT MAX(insdt) AS date  FROM '+@tablename+'')
DECLARE @yourvariable date
SELECT @yourvariable=date1 FROM @table1

DECLARE @userDate date

IF @userDate>@yourvariable
BEGIN
   SELECT  top 1 text FROM MyTable ORDER BY [date] DESC
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
   SELECT Text FROM MyTable WHERE Date>= @userDate
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN T.Date IS NULL THEN M.TEXT 
        ELSE T.TEXT 
    END AS TEXT
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY Date DESC
    ) AS M
    LEFT JOIN MyTable T ON T.Date>= @userDate11
```

This is one of several ways to solve the problem.  The `TOP(1)` and `ORDER BY Date DESC` gives you the fallback record.  The original table aliased `T` is consigned as the optional partner in the `LEFT JOIN`.  This allows it to return no records, while still retaining the singular record from the derived table aliased `M`. The `CASE` statement then tests to see if we actually managed to get anything from T using `WHEN T.Date IS NULL` - if `T` is not empty, all the `TEXT` values will come from `T`, otherwise we will have just the single `TEXT` value from `M`, being the one for the `MAX(Date)`.